# displaying the json data in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's my json:

```
groups=[
  {
    ["red pencil","blue pencil","yellow pencil"]
  },
  {
    ["big rubber","small rubber"]
  },
];
```

How can i display the json data in angular 2 using typescript.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: This json is not valid. Check it.

Comment: @AlexKojin I know it don't have any key value. But that's how i wanted the data in json. Can you please tell me what's wrong with that data?

Comment: You need to remove brackets because they required keys. You should get `[["red pencil", "blue pencil", "yellow pencil"],["big rubber", "small rubber"]]`

Comment: Yes that is no JSON that is something you came up with ... remove the curly brackets and you have a 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

```
{{groups | json}}
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let g of groups">
  <div>Group:</div>
  <div *ngFor="let i of g">{{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding to this you can also wrap with a pre tags to make it nicer. <pre>{{groups | json}}</pre>

Answer (score 0):

> JSON is similar to JavaScript’s way of writing arrays and objects,
>   with a few restrictions. All property names have to be surrounded by
>   double quotes, and only simple data expressions are allowed—no
>   function calls, variables, or anything that involves actual
>   computation. Comments are not allowed in JSON.

if your json is valid, you could use `JSON.parse` to convert it to js Object and use `*ngFor` to traversal or `{{ data | json }}` to display it.